# extracting digital certificate from tcp/ip packet

Tags: ssl, certificate

I am writing a program that will be located in the middle of a SSL connection. In other words, a SSL client and server are connecting but the connection packets pass through my program. I have full access to packet payloads and I know that client is sending its digital certificate in SSL handshaking. How can I find and extract clients' digital certificate in/from these packets?

Comment: Using what library? Both `OpenSSL` and `JSSE` give you access to the SSL Session, from which you can get the peer certificate. Nothing to do with TCP packets at all really.

Comment: You have access to ssl session only if you are the server side, but I am not the server of this connection I am just a node in the middle which only sees tcp/ip packets

Comment: That's not correct. You have access to the SSL session from both sides. It exists on both sides. It would be pointless otherwise. You haven't answered my question about libraries. If you are just a transparent proxy you have no hope, as the relevant parts of the handshake may be encrypted. I suggest you have a good look at [RFC 2246](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2246.txt) before proceeding any further.

Comment: I am sure transparent proxies can get client's certificates because this part of handshake is not encrypted. If you watch a SSL packet stream in wireshark you see that wireshark can show the certificates, however it is a passive sniffer, so it is possible.

Comment: The *entire* handshake is encrypted if there has been a prior handshake on the same connection. And the client isn't obliged to present the same certificate he did before. What you are attempting is infeasible in general. You can get the *first* certificate. Read the RFC.